# SQL Update with SUM from other fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried many of the solutions available on Stack to solve this problem, but what seems to work for others, doesn't work for me. My situation is very simple and I seem to be unable to simplify the provided solutions down to what I need.

I have two tables:

**master**

```
M_ID, Name, total_number
```

**things**

```
T_ID, M_ID, thing, number
```

I can query the SUM, however I have been unable to update master.total_number with the sum. I've tried all sorts of solutions and I really think I am over thinking this so I give up!

Here is the query i wish to achieve, knowing full well this doesn't work as is:

```
UPDATE master
set master.total_number = (SELECT SUM(things.number) 
                           from things 
                           where M_ID = 1234) 
where master.M_ID = 1234
```

Comment: Can you post what solution you tried and what the outcome was?

Comment: Don't store values computed from other table data, it will end up with data inconsistency. Create a view instead (or perhaps a _computed column_.)

Comment: This isn't my choice. We do not have a method of calculating outside of the database (unless we pivot chart it in Excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do `APPLY` with `update` :

```
UPDATE m
     SET m.total_number = s.sum_no
FROM master m CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(t.number) as sum_no
      FROM things t
      WHER t.M_ID = m.M_ID
     ) s;
WHERE m.M_ID = 1234;
```

However, your update query needs to be correlated so, it would be :

```
UPDATE m
     SET M.total_number = (SELECT SUM(t.number) 
                           FROM things t
                           WHERE t.M_ID = m.M_ID
                          )
FROM master m 
WHERE m.M_ID = 1234;
```

Comment: I get the same error:  "[FATAL] A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause"

Comment: @Mattrajotte . . . Both versions should work (I fixed a table alias).

Comment: same error...[FATAL] A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause

Comment: This ended up working. I realized, not all 'number' fields had a value. I added t.number is not null to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
UPDATE m
SET    m.total_number = theSum.Val
FROM   master  m
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT [Val] = SUM(number)
    FROM   things
    WHERE  things.M_ID = m.M_ID
) theSum
--WHERE  M_ID = 1234      -- <=== Optionally...just for a specific ID.
```

Comment: I've tried this solution before and I get "[FATAL] A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause"